# How to delay sensor data sample rate to one second?

Tags: android, sensors

I am currently sending data from various sensors (Accelerometer, Gyroscope etc.) to a database using AsyncTask.

I have each service for each sensor that sends the data back to mainActivity, via broadcasting, once onSensorChanged is triggered.

The problem is that sensor data change so quickly that the database is flooded in a few seconds.
What I want is to trigger the onSensorChanged method every second, but passing a sampling period of 1 second (1*10^6 us) doesn't have any effect at all.

Is there any other way to accomplish a 1 second delay?

Comment: Show us some relevant code :)

Comment: Just take a time hack and drop the samples you don't want.

Comment: @greeble31 yeah I could use a counter on my main activity for example and send the data to database only when that coutner reaches X. However, onsensorChanged method on all of my services will continue executing continuously and this is not battery efficient I believe.

Comment: Well, you've already done all that you can to describe to the system what you want, and it's doing the best it can do for you, in that regard. As the docs say, it's only a suggested delay. Since (given your desired interval) you are basically committed to keeping the CPU awake, I think the marginal effect on battery performance would be minimal, provided you can efficiently discard unwanted samples. (And the point is, you're not going to do any better, unless you relax your constraints.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Developer site

> The data delay (or sampling rate) controls the interval at which
> sensor events are sent to your application via the onSensorChanged()
> callback method. The default data delay is suitable for monitoring
> typical screen orientation changes and uses a delay of 200,000
> microseconds. You can specify other data delays, such as
> SENSOR_DELAY_GAME (20,000 microsecond delay), SENSOR_DELAY_UI (60,000
> microsecond delay), or SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST (0 microsecond delay). As
> of Android 3.0 (API Level 11) you can also specify the delay as an
> absolute value (in microseconds)
>
> The delay that you specify is only a suggested delay. The Android
> system and other applications can alter this delay. As a best
> practice, you should specify the largest delay that you can because
> the system typically uses a smaller delay than the one you specify
> (that is, you should choose the slowest sampling rate that still meets
> the needs of your application). Using a larger delay imposes a lower
> load on the processor and therefore uses less power.
>
> There is no public method for determining the rate at which the sensor
> framework is sending sensor events to your application; however, you
> can use the timestamps that are associated with each sensor event to
> calculate the sampling rate over several events. You should not have
> to change the sampling rate (delay) once you set it. If for some
> reason you do need to change the delay, you will have to unregister
> and reregister the sensor listener.

Hope this helps. You may use additional service/ background thread in order to achieve exact time delay before database insertion method.

Answer (score 0):

Highly recommend looking at reactive frameworks, [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) in particular (there's RxKotlin as well). Once you get used to it, it will greatly improve quality of code and robustness on i/o tasks. It supports desired behavior out of the box ([debounce operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html))